# What is the Sql struct equivalent to load teradata tables

Tags: java, teradata

I have an application which loads the data in XML to Oracle tables. Now we are moving to teradata. Using Java a DAO is populated and that DAO calls oracle stored procedure after mapping DTO a sql struct object. If I want to do the same for Teradata, there is no such object as sql struct object which I can load through Java. Is there anyway I can use some method to interact with Teradata directly from DTO.

Is there any way to populate an XML directly to teradata without loading to any landing table?

Comment: Is there any way to populate an XML directly to teradata without loading to any landing table

Comment: You can *edit* your question to include your secondary question, rather than posting it as a comment. You should see an `edit` link below your question, to the left.